# Xcode 5.1.1 generates a project where I cannot open Core Data Model Editor

Tags: core-data, xcode5

I use Xcode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9.4. When I create a new project by going
File > New > Project
iOS Application > Empty Application
Next
Product name: CoreDataTest
Devices: iPhone
Use Core Data: checked
Next
Create
I expect Core Data Model Editor to open, but it doesn't. There is a big icon with object graphs in the center, and I don't get table view or graph view editor like lots of tutorial videos on the Internet suggests.

Control clicking CoreData.xcdatamodeld gives me an option "Open As", but only "Preview" appears, which does nothing.
So I
control click CoreDataTest.xcdatamodeld > Show in Finder
control click CoreDataTest.xcdatamodeld in Finder > Show Package Contents
There's a hidden file named ".xccurrentversion", so I opened it with a text editor.
The content looks exactly like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"       "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

To me, it seems Xcode is not generating projects right at all. This happens also when
- creating single view project and adding CoreData.Framework and Core Data Model later, and
- creating Master-Detail Application
Your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the above problem by creating another user profile on my Mac.

Another possible and easier fix could be to delete user preference of Xcode at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
but this didn't apply to my situation. On my old (and possibly corrupt) user profile, flushing the preference file didn't resolve the issue.

FYI, you might want to try deleting the preference file before creating another profile.